# VSTO and Outlook 2003 Context menus

Tags: outlook, vsto, contextmenu

I want to have outlook 2003/2007 integration with my application using VSTO. With outlook 2007 it's OK - I have all the hooks I need but with outlook 2003 I can't find how to add context menu item to the mail items in the inbox. I didn't find any event handler for populating the context menu like the one in the 2007 version.

Do you know any workaround?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10771686/1411687

Answer (score 4):

Site is still viewable in the archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20160405050041/http://www.developerzen.com/2005/04/04/adding-a-button-to-outlooks-context-menu/

To add a button to the Outlook explorer context menu you need to get the “Context Menu” CommandBar.
This command bar instance is only created when the user right clicks in the explorer so in order to know when such a bar is
created you have to listen to the OnUpdate event of the Explorer’s CommandBars collection.
Inside the OnUpdate event handler you can check if the context menu CommandBar exist:

```
CommandBar bar = ActiveExplorer.CommandBars[“Context Menu”];
```

After getting the context menu CommandBar you need to change it’s Protection property to allow customization, add your button, and change the Protection back.

Comment: dead link, unfortunately

Comment: @Mike Found the article in the internet archive and copied contents here